# Catching IP address changes

Tags: c#, .net

I want to be able to monitor the IP address and log it to file using C# , is this possible and how

Comment: Kind of loose question - do you mean the running machine's IP, incoming request IPs? What?

Comment: The IP address of the computer on a subnet, or the global IP (e.g. the one that shows up if you go to a site like www.whatismyip.com)?

Comment: There are plenty of questions like this one. I'm sure he can find his answer only by browsing old threads....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at the [NetworkAddressChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkchange.networkaddresschanged.aspx) event.